# Create User-Defined Table Name in C# MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

Good Day Devs!

I want to know on how to create user-defined table name. I use 3 tier Architecture:
[image: Form]

BAL:

```
public void Purchase1(BELPurchase BELPur)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = dbcon.getcon();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [@Title] (VENDOR varchar(1000), ADDRESS varchar(1000), CONTROL_NO varchar(20), DATE date, TERMS varchar(20), QTY int, ITD varchar(1000), UP int, TP int, ALTOT int, REQUEST_BY varchar(500)) " +
            "INSERT INTO [@Title] VALUES (@Vendor,@Address,@CtrlNo,@Date,@Terms,@Qty1,@ITD1,@UP1,@TP1,@ATT,@REQBY)";// lagay mo insert query mo
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title1",BELPur.Title)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vendor", BELPur.Vendor);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", BELPur.Address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CtrlNo", BELPur.CtrlNo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", BELPur.Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Terms", BELPur.Terms);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty1", BELPur.Qty1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITD1", BELPur.ItD1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UP1", BELPur.UP1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TP1", BELPur.TP1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ATT", BELPur.AllTot);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQBY", BELPur.ReqBy);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

DAL:

```
public class DBPurCon
{
    public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = DESKTOP-ANJELLO\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = db_ADAPurchase; Persist Security Info = True; User Id = sa; Password = mm4;");

    public SqlConnection getcon()
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();
        else if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
        return con;
    }
```

BEL:

```
   public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string CtrlNo { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Terms { get; set; }
    public string ReqBy { get; set; }
    public string AllTot { get; set; }

    public string Qty1 { get; set; }
    public string ITD1 { get; set; }
    public string UP1 { get; set; }
    public string TP1 { get; set; }
```

Scenario: The code will create table named by Title typed by the user. After creating the table, All fields will now insert into the table named by the Title. 
[image]
Thank you for helping me!

Comment: What is the question or the problem ? Don't use one global connection DBPurCon, this is bad practise. Connection pool is your friend. also up1 and tp1 and probably others are defined as strings in your class, but in the database as int. Don't do that define them as int in your class.

Comment: So you wanna generate a temp table then add items to this temp table, for what reason? Is it because u wanna generate an entire table and send to database in one go?

Comment: Probably, Yes Sir @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen.. Can C# do that?

Comment: You can, but then you don't want to to create a table for each row which you  do now, you want, and you want a stored procedure afterwards to handle the the tempoary temple, to add permenently to the database

Comment: Google value type parameter C# then you should find examples that you need

Comment: Sir @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I edited my post.. I want to be like that in the picture below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two commands, not in a single command. It can be done in a single command but you have to use SQLServer SMO libraries to be able to specify `GO` statements in your commands.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = getcon();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = String.Format("CREATE TABLE [{0}] (VENDOR varchar(1000), ADDRESS varchar(1000), CONTROL_NO varchar(20), DATE date, TERMS varchar(20), QTY int, ITD varchar(1000), UP int, TP int, ALTOT int, REQUEST_BY varchar(500)) ", BELPur.Title);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
cmd2.Connection = getcon();
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd2.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO [{0}] VALUES (@Vendor,@Address,@CtrlNo,@Date,@Terms,@Qty1,@ITD1,@UP1,@TP1,@ATT,@REQBY)", BELPur.Title);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vendor", BELPur.Vendor);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", BELPur.Address);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CtrlNo", BELPur.CtrlNo);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", BELPur.Date);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Terms", BELPur.Terms);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty1", BELPur.Qty1);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITD1", BELPur.ItD1);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UP1", BELPur.UP1);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TP1", BELPur.TP1);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ATT", BELPur.AllTot);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQBY", BELPur.ReqBy);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also I've changed how the name of the table that is being passed to SQL Server, because you can't use it as a variable this way so I've used `String.Format`.

The cleaner way, I think, you would have to create a stored procedure to create the table and insert the values in it from your parameters.

And as Henrik Bøgelund Lavstsen have said, I think the database design it is not the optimal one to go with. Think about when you will have 1k requests => 1k tables.

Comment: Sir @mihail-stancescu I'm sure the request will not become 1K up.. Thank you sir! :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new table, just add to the existing table if its 1 row at the time, this however will not help with updating, then you need the code a bit,

```
public void Purchase1(BELPurchase BELPur)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = dbcon.getcon();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Others VALUES (@Vendor,@Address,@CtrlNo,@Date,@Terms,@Qty1,@ITD1,@UP1,@TP1,@ATT,@REQBY)";// lagay mo insert query mo
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title1",BELPur.Title)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vendor", BELPur.Vendor);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", BELPur.Address);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CtrlNo", BELPur.CtrlNo);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", BELPur.Date);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Terms", BELPur.Terms);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty1", BELPur.Qty1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITD1", BELPur.ItD1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UP1", BELPur.UP1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TP1", BELPur.TP1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ATT", BELPur.AllTot);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQBY", BELPur.ReqBy);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

based on the comment, i think you should rethink you database structure first, then you can add to it, here is an example of a structure you could use:

[image: Basic structure of image]

The reason for a table for vendor and address is because in you immage, i see you have a drop down, so from that you can select an existing in database, and just have a relation between the items.
However this has gone off-topic, so you should consider creating new questions based on something specific.

Comment: Sir @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen my system always need to create new table because new table means new request. So I want to know a code that create table and insert the items in the created table at the same time.. Thank you for helping me sir!

Comment: That is not a very good database structure you building, cause databases might collide with each other, instead, you should create a table for request and a table for request lines, that has a foreign key to request id.